# No more than 1 “maintenance_policy” blocks are allowed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to build a dynamic block for a Redis instance (google provider), but I keep getting this error while planning. Here is the code:
variables.tf

```
variable "redis_maintenance_policy" {
    type = object({
        description = string,
        weekly_maintenance_window = object({
            day = string,
            start_time = object({
                hours   = number,
                minutes = number,
                nanos   = number,
                seconds = number,
            })
        })
    })

    default = {
        description = "Maintenance policy description here",
        weekly_maintenance_window = {
            day = "TUESDAY",
            start_time = {
                hours   = 0,
                minutes = 30,
                nanos   = 0,
                seconds = 0,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I tried to create the `dynamic` block by using like this:
main.tf

```
resource "google_redis_instance" "cache" {
  auth_enabled            = false
  authorized_network      = data.google_compute_network.gcp-network.id
  connect_mode            = "PRIVATE_SERVICE_ACCESS"
  display_name            = var.redis_display_name

  labels = var.redis_labels

  memory_size_gb          = var.redis_memory_size_gb
  name                    = var.redis_name
  project                 = var.redis_project
  read_replicas_mode      = var.redis_read_replicas_mode
  redis_configs           = var.redis_configs
  redis_version           = var.redis_version
  region                  = var.redis_region
  replica_count           = var.redis_replica_count
  reserved_ip_range       = var.redis_reserved_ip_range
  secondary_ip_range      = var.redis_secondary_ip_range
  tier                    = var.redis_tier
  transit_encryption_mode = "DISABLED"

dynamic maintenance_policy {
    for_each = var.redis_maintenance_policy
    iterator = policy
    content {
        description = policy.value.description
        weekly_maintenance_window {
            day = policy.value.weekly_maintenance_window.day
            start_time {
                hours   = policy.value.start_time.hours
                minutes = policy.value.start_time.minutes
                nanos   = policy.value.start_time.nanos
                seconds = policy.value.start_time.seconds
              }
            }
          }
        }
  }
depends_on = [google_service_networking_connection.private_service_connection]

}
```

It keeps giving me lots of errors:

```
╷
│ Error: Too many maintenance_policy blocks
│ 
│   on main.tf line 44, in resource "google_redis_instance" "cache":
│   44:     content {
│ 
│ No more than 1 "maintenance_policy" blocks are allowed
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on main.tf line 45, in resource "google_redis_instance" "cache":
│   45:         description = policy.value.description
│     ├────────────────
│     │ policy.value is "Maintenance policy description here"
│ 
│ Can't access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).
╵
```

I already tried to make `dynamic` block for each of the nested object, same problem. I also tried to `flatten` the object and see if I could access it locally. No success as well.

Any hints on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Well, the error is pretty clear: you cannot have more than one `maintenance_policy` block, and it seems your variable is trying to add more than one. The other error is related to how you have defined the variable and its values.

Comment: it doesn't have more than one element in that object, and there is no attempt to create more than one `maintenance_policy`. That's what I am clueless about.

Comment: Can you add the entire code block for the resource?

Answer (score 2):

Since only one block is allowed, it seems `dynamic` cannot be used. Keeping that in mind, the following should work:

```
 maintenance_policy {
        description = var.redis_maintenance_policy.description
        weekly_maintenance_window {
            day = var.redis_maintenance_policy.weekly_maintenance_window.day
            start_time {
                hours   = var.redis_maintenance_policy.weekly_maintenance_window.start_time.hours
                minutes = var.redis_maintenance_policy.weekly_maintenance_window.start_time.minutes
                nanos   = var.redis_maintenance_policy.weekly_maintenance_window.start_time.nanos
                seconds = var.redis_maintenance_policy.weekly_maintenance_window.start_time.seconds
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Beat me to making a similar comment. Given the error message and usage there is no discernible reason to use a dynamic block here, and seemingly best path forward would definitely be to access the variable values directly.

Comment: make sense... but what doesn't make sense to me it that: `for_each` should evaluate to only 1 element (the only existing in the object) no?

Comment: It should, but terraform cannot assume how many elements `dynamic` will provide, at least that's how I read the error.

Comment: is there a way to inspect the content of the variables once we start running the plan? then I could know what's really going on under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

With the answer from @Marko, I was able to find a solution.

```
dynamic maintenance_policy {
    for_each = var.redis_maintenance_policy != null ? [1] : []

    content {
      description = var.redis_maintenance_policy.description

      weekly_maintenance_window {
          day = var.redis_maintenance_policy.weekly_maintenance_window.day

          start_time {
              hours   = var.redis_maintenance_policy.weekly_maintenance_window.start_time.hours
              minutes = var.redis_maintenance_policy.weekly_maintenance_window.start_time.minutes
              nanos   = var.redis_maintenance_policy.weekly_maintenance_window.start_time.nanos
              seconds = var.redis_maintenance_policy.weekly_maintenance_window.start_time.seconds
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

This way, I was able to dynamically create the `maintenance_policy` block. If the customer want it, they can provide the variable, if not, then nothing will be provided.

PS: I only realised now that the `default` from the variable led to a wrong assumption, this is not mandatory block.